# get transaction neo4j spring data

Tags: transactions, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

How can I get the transaction object to be able to use it in my service layer when I'm using this configuration?

```
<neo4j:config storeDirectory="D:/neo4j-2.0.1/data/mydb"/>   
<neo4j:repositories base-package="com.myapp.repository" />

<tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy"/>
```

I'm using Neo4j 2.0.1, Spring data Neo4j 3.0.0 and Spring 3.2.8

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject NeoTemplate object into your service, if you are not going to use repositories. Transaction can be managed as always with @Transactional annotation!

Cheers,
Lorenzo

Comment: Also for other injected beans like services you can use @Transactional